# how do I draw the following?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I am trying to convert the image below into tikz.

So far what I got is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images


\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every rectangle node/.style={draw},every circle node/.style={draw,double}]


\node(aspectnode) [black, minimum size=3cm] at (0,0) {A} ;
\node(mainnode) [black, minimum size=5cm, minimum height=3cm, below right=of aspectnode] at (0,0) {B} ;
\node(helpernode) [black, minimum size=3cm, minimum height=1cm, right=of aspectnode] at (0,0) {C} ;
\node(ahelpernode) [black, minimum size=3cm, minimum height=2cm, right=of mainnode] at (0,0) {D} ;
\node(bhelpernode) [black, minimum size=3cm, minimum height=2cm, below right=of mainnode] at (0,0) {E} ;
\node(chelpernode) [black, minimum size=3cm, minimum height=2cm, below=of mainnode] at (0,0) {F} ;
\node(dhelpernode) [black, minimum size=3cm, minimum height=2cm, left=of chelpernode] at (0,0) {F} ;


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I don't need a full answer, but I am trying to understand why I am nowhere near (I can play with sizes, that's not the issue) - I can't quite understand why my relative positioning doesn't work. I tried to change it to right=1cm of [nameofnode] but that didn't help).

I was hoping at first to create a skeleton such that each of the lettered rectangle would map to a rectangle in the drawing.

I can add the arrows later...

Another question is how to create the rectangle with the squiggly lined edge at the bottom.

If I just create the main "graph" I can work from there, and I played with \path, \draw, etc. and can't quite get it right. I really wish relative positioning was easy.

The colors don't matter either, I will fix that later, I think I know how. It is just the positioning of the rectangles, the arrows and the squiggly lines. Any help appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You are giving tikz conflicting instructions when you say `...below right=of aspectnode] at (0,0)` because this contains both `below right` and `at`. Also, you need to load the `positioning` library. This means to get closer to your desired outcome remove all the `at (0,0)` in the nodes (you can leave it for the first one, in the current setting it won't make a difference).

Comment: those two tips changed the picture completely (no pun intended)... the picture makes much more sense now. I will continue to work from there. thank you. (though the squiggly line issue is still not clear to me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The positioning issues got already addressed in the comment. I also made no attempts to precisely arrange the boxes as in the target picture, nor did I draw the arrows.

In order to have frames around the nodes, one can employ `pic`s. The styles `ambient` and `ambient'` illustrate this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% loads graphicx
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%every rectangle node/.style={draw},
    every circle node/.style={draw,double},
    ambient/.style={rectangle,draw=none,
        append after command={pic{ambient=#1}}},
    pics/ambient/.style={code={
        \path[even odd rule,fill=#1] 
            ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=1ex]\tikzlastnode.north west)
            rectangle 
            ([xshift=1ex,yshift=-1ex]\tikzlastnode.south east)
            (\tikzlastnode.north west)
            rectangle 
            (\tikzlastnode.south east)
            ;
        \draw ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=1ex]\tikzlastnode.north west)
            rectangle 
            ([xshift=1ex,yshift=-1ex]\tikzlastnode.south east);
    }},
    ambient'/.style={rectangle,draw=none,
        append after command={pic{ambient'=#1}}},
    pics/ambient'/.style={code={
        \path[even odd rule,fill=#1] 
            ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=1ex]\tikzlastnode.north west)
            -| 
            ([xshift=1ex,yshift=-2ex]\tikzlastnode.south east)
            to[out=190,in=-10]
            ([yshift=-2ex]\tikzlastnode.south)
            to[out=170,in=10]
            ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=-2ex]\tikzlastnode.south west)
            -- cycle
            (\tikzlastnode.north west)
            rectangle 
            (\tikzlastnode.south east)
            ;
        \draw ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=1ex]\tikzlastnode.north west)
            -| 
            ([xshift=1ex,yshift=-2ex]\tikzlastnode.south east)
            to[out=190,in=-10]
            ([yshift=-2ex]\tikzlastnode.south)
            to[out=170,in=10]
            ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=-2ex]\tikzlastnode.south west)
            -- cycle;
    }}]


\node(aspectnode) [draw, minimum size=3cm] at (0,0) {A} ;
\node(mainnode) [draw, minimum size=5cm, minimum height=3cm, below right=of aspectnode] {B} ;
\node(helpernode) [minimum size=3cm, minimum height=1cm, right=of aspectnode,ambient=orange] {C} ;
\node(ahelpernode) [draw, minimum size=3cm, minimum height=2cm, right=of mainnode] {D} ;
\node(bhelpernode) [draw, minimum size=3cm, minimum height=2cm, below right=of mainnode]{E} ;
\node(chelpernode) [draw, minimum size=3cm, minimum height=2cm, below=of mainnode] {F} ;
\node(dhelpernode) [minimum size=3cm, minimum height=2cm, left=of chelpernode,ambient'=red] {G} ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]